# CSS3 Border-radius and Box-shadow has wierd corners

Tags: css

I want to make a combination of Border-radius and Box-shadow, which worked out fine. But when i look at the corners there are some missing pixels (transparent). I cant figure out how to remove this, so it will look as if the two shadows were one.

You might have to zoom in to see the error!

I am using Mozilla Firefox 36.0.1 and it looks the same in Internet Explorer 11.

Here is an example :http://jsfiddle.net/DannyThillemann/egs9umhn/

```
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px 2px #888888, 0px 0px 2px 2px #888888;
```

Comment: just by changing the colors of `box-shadow` looks fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/exr31f9m/)

Comment: Sorry to say that i see the same white pixels between the two shadows. Try zooming in...

Comment: I don't see the problem with this only when zooming ( w/o zooming barely can't see) .. anyhow take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/exr31f9m/1/)

Comment: I agree that the color changes helped and that it is barely visible. Though i want the same color on both shadows. I appreciate the effort, but it is not what i am aiming for =)

Answer (score -1):

This issue happens because of the css inset property, If you remove inset you will not see the issue.

ex: box-shadow:0px 0px 2px 2px #888888, 0px 0px 2px 2px #888888;